# Limit data in requests in Api Lravel

Tags: laravel, rest, api, request, vue.js

I have an API in laravel 5.4 and used Vue Resource to consume this backend. But when making the requests I bring all the information that is in the database and that is about 10k of questions. I would limit this for example to 100 questions and make a next request.

My api repository

```
    class QuestionRepository implements QuestionRepositoryInterface
    {

        protected $question;

        public function __construct(Question $question)
        {
            $this->question = $question;
        }

        public function all(){
            $data = $this->question->all();

            return $data;
        }

        public function find($id)
        {
            return $this->question->find($id);
        }

        public function findByTopic($id)
        {
            $questions = $this->question->where('topic_idtopic', '=', $id)->get();

            return $questions;
        }
    public function findBySubject($id)
    {
        $questions = $this->question->where('subject_idsubject', '=', $id)->get();

        return $questions;
    }
}
```

My Vue code

```
mounted(){

    this.$http.get(window.api+'subject').then((response) => {
        this.subjects = response.data
    });

    this.$http.get(window.api+'questions/count').then((response) => {
        this.count = response.body
    });

    this.status = 1
},
```

My Question Controller

```
   //Todas as questões
    public function index()
    {
        $questions = $this->questionRepository->all();

        return Response::json([
            'questions' => $this->questionTransformer->transformCollection($questions->all())
        ]);
    }

    public function count()
    {
        $count = $this->questionRepository->all()->count();

        return Response::json($count);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $questions = $this->questionRepository->find($id);

        if(!$questions)  return $this->responseNotFound('Question doesn\'t exist');

        return Response::json([
            'questions' => $this->questionTransformer->transformCollection($questions->all())
        ]);
    }
    public function showBySubject($id)
    {
        $questions = $this->questionRepository->findBySubject($id);

        return Response::json([
            'questions' => $this->questionTransformer->transformCollection($questions->all())
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pagination. Either change your `all()` function or make a new function function.

```
public function pagination($limit = 100){
    $data = $this->question->paginate($limit);
    return $data;
}
```

More here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination

Comment: And what would the request look like in Vue?

Comment: Oh wait. You will have to leave `all()` as is and make another function called `paginate()` because from VueJS when you call `count()` it gives you the total count. However, paginate will also give you the total count. Simply call it the same way you call the others and `console.log(response)` to see what it returns.